# What was Pong called in Britain?

Tags: history, atari, arcade, pong

Pong, the electronic ping-pong game invented by Atari in 1972, was the first really successful video game.

In Britain, 'pong' was also slang for a nasty smell, and I remember reading somewhere, a long time ago, that Atari became aware of this and had a discussion about what if anything to do about it, but I cannot for the life of me remember what the conclusion was, nor can I find any mention of it on Google.

What was the game called when it was released in Britain? Did they just keep the name Pong, or did they change it to something else?

Comment: As an aside, perhaps I could mention at this point the Wireless World "Tele-Tennis" design from about 1975, made up almost entirely of 555 timer chips.

Comment: rwallace, for some reason I always assumed you were a Brit. May I ask where you come from?

Comment: What a cool side note ... guess that's the GB equivalence of the VC20 vs. VIC20 urban legend. Didn't happen but sounds like people would love to believe.

Comment: @OmarL from his posting times he's either nocturnal European or lives on the other side of the pond :))

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd - an awe-full thing & thanks for the steer to it: 12*NE555, 16*SN7400, 6 PCBs, from Practical Wireless Jul-Oct 1974, available https://worldradiohistory.com/UK/Practical/Wireless/70s/PW-1974-07.pdf onwards

Comment: I have a weird feeling I've heard it was named "PANG" somewhere but I've never seen it, and I'm far too youthful to have been around when it came out.

Comment: @OmarL I live in Ireland. And yes, am quite nocturnal :)

Comment: @JohnU --- [Pang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buster_Bros.) was a later game, in which players shot balloons with a harpoon.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Pong.

I've lived in the UK for many years and never heard it  called Ping! That is news to me. Now, when talking about the video game called Pong, we call it Pong.

Comment: Yes, same here -- when I lived in the UK (late 90s/early 2000s), it was definitely known as Pong. But then again, that was 25 years after the fact.

Comment: What do you guys call Git? Or the Gimp?

Comment: The same, git and gimp

Comment: @dotancohen "Git" was named with the British meaning in mind.

Comment: What other meaning is there for git

Comment: @OmarL - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(slang) esp. footnote 11

Comment: Torvalds has said that he has two major pieces of software named after him -- "Linux" and "git".

Comment: @MartinBa's right, though IMO the Wikipedia article plays down the most relevant meaning - someone irritating and grumpy.

Comment: Living in the UK "for many years" isn't particularly great credentials for confirming what something was named nearly 50 years ago. I've lived in the UK all my life, but that life started 10 years after Pong was developed, so my personal recollection is pretty much irrelevant here.

Comment: Yeah! Ping? What is Ping? Never heard of it. It was always Pong.

Answer (score 27):

**According to Atari co-founder Nolan Bushnell, Pong was marketed as "Ping" in the UK.** He said so [in this 1982 BBC interview](https://twitter.com/BBCArchive/status/1200420398178816001) ("because evidently Pong is not a good word in England"), and repeated it 16 years later in this [interview with German online magazine Telepolis](https://www.heise.de/tp/features/Interview-mit-Nolan-Bushnell-Erfinder-von-Pong-und-Atari-Gruender-3440093.html). If nothing else, Bushnell is probably the source of the story you heard.

Also, Pong is indeed a British informal word for "an unpleasant odor" ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pong)) or "a disagreeable or offensive smell; stink" ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pong)), lending credibility to Bushnell's claim.

On the other hand, several people in this thread have stated that Pong has always been Pong in the UK, whereas no-one can remember it being called Ping. So Bushnell may be misremembering (perhaps this was discussed at Atari, but never implemented?), or Atari may have reverted to Pong after a couple of machines. Or Bushnell is playing a really long-time prank.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! What search term did you use? Perhaps my Google-fu needs sharpening.

Comment: "atari pong britain" - 7th hit

Comment: I think this was either a joke or a misunderstanding on Bushnell's part.

Comment: This answer has been accepted, but it is incorrect. The UK version of Pong was called Pong. UK citizens are familiar with Ping Pong (table tennis) and there was no scope for confusion about the name. Bushnell must have been joking.

Comment: We had some such device in the early 1970s, but I couldn't tell you what it **was** actually called.  But I'm pretty sure it **wasn't** called "Ping".   FWIW, "pong" as a synonym for "smell" isn't a particularly bad word. It's not like [naming a chocolate bar after the noise a horse makes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snickers#History).

Comment: As a 39-year-old, I've only ever heard it called Pong.

Comment: @another-dave I've never heard a horse say "marathon".  Seriously though, while I'm not old enough to have seen Pong when it came out, everything I have seen in the UK called it Pong (or was a clone)

Comment: In defence of this answer, it should be pointed out that the clip of Bushnell making the claim is from the **very much British** BBC, 10 years after the game's release, and doesn't appear to be challenged in either the original clip or the Twitter feed, also run by the BBC, that re-posted it. If people want to challenge, it would be good to have stronger evidence than people's memories 40 years on.

Comment: @spikey_richie Your memories of what it was called _nine years before you were born_ are unlikely to be all that accurate. It seems entirely plausible to me that, like the Marathon/Snickers example given earlier, it was initially marketed as Ping, but then became sufficiently famous internationally that calling it Pong everywhere made more sense than localising it.

Comment: Anecdotally, & speaking as a 60-year-old who has lived in the UK my entire life - though I never owned the original as a child (only in later compilation versions), I cannot recall any instance of it ever being referred to as 'ping', only ever pong. Being about 14 at the time, it would have been the perfect age to compare it to 'a bad smell' but I can't recall anyone considered that particularly amusing either.

Comment: Just a more recent example, people were laughing at the name "iPad", because they were thinking of the feminine product "pads". That wasn't an issue and the rest is history.

Comment: @IMSoP It being "very much British" is why this is likely to be dry humour, rather than a literal answer.

Answer (score 9):

It was marketed as PONG (note the capitals) and can be seen (subject to current restrictions) at British retro preservation venues like the Centre for Computing History.

http://www.computinghistory.org.uk/det/4007/Atari-PONG/

Comment: That's an American box.  It says "color TV" on the side.  Also "D batteries", which would have been "U2" in Britain.

Comment: more likely "HP2" as I remember them, @another-dave

Comment: @scruss -  Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_battery_sizes#Non-standard_brand-specific_names), HP2 was an Ever-Ready designation for a zinc-chloride U2 battery, with SP2 for the cheaper zinc-carbon U2.

Comment: yes, @another-dave — just I don't think I ever saw a battery in the UK that actually said "U2" on it, just SP2 and HP2 from several brands, not just Ever Ready. Though they did [exist](https://www.vintage-radio.net/forum/showpost.php?p=113076&postcount=15).

Comment: That's the 1975 Pong home console. Given the 1972 reference in the question, I thought the OP was referring to the 1972 arcade machine?